# CreateInstanceFrom and Unwrap fails to load assembly when run in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

I have a WCF service which uses MEF components to handle different request types.

The service creates a new appDomain with properties set in order to shadowcopy the MEF components and allow them to by dynamically removed/replaced and then it creates a plugin manager object which uses the MEF framework to load the components.

```
private void CreatePluginManager()
{                   
   // creates a ShadowCopy of the MEF DLL's and any other DLL's in the ShadowCopyDirectories)
   var setup = new AppDomainSetup
   {
       CachePath = @"C:\Websites\Sites\tstNewNrates\plugins",  
       ShadowCopyFiles = "true",
       ShadowCopyDirectories = Code.Utilities.DefaultCarrierPluginDirectory,
       ApplicationBase = Environment.CurrentDirectory
   };

   domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Host_AppDomain", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, setup);

   string AssemblyPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        pluginMgr = (RatesWebService.Code.CarrierPluginManager)domain.CreateInstanceFrom(AssemblyPath, typeof(RatesWebService.Code.CarrierPluginManager).FullName).Unwrap();
    }
```

This code will work fine when I host the WCF service locally in a console application but when I deploy to IIS 7.5 it fails to find a common library dependency which is used by both the WCF service and each of the plugins even though this assembly is located in the same folder has the service and each of the plugins.

Locally the shadow copy of all the files is created. On IIS the copy is never made.

Comment: could it be that when you run it yourself it's in 64 bit and in IIS it's 32 bit (or the other way around)?

Comment: And also check what .NET framework is enabled for your application pool